# Does java grpc server use one thread to process a request to its end when it is received?

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

According to my previous habit of using springboot web, when receiving a request, Tomcat will use one thread to process these core logic, except for asynchronous methods.
But now I am using grpc-server, and I found that two threads are used to process one request, is this normal?

I hope that answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All grpc-java service methods are closer to the async Tomcat approach (today; we'll see what changes take place to better support virtual threads). You are free to do synchronous operations within the threads, but you can return before the RPC is complete and make the thread available for another operation.

At most one thread per RPC is delivering callbacks to the application. But which thread that is can change over the course of the RPC.

Comment: If someone enables Virtual Threads on the Framework level (Spring Boot, Quarkus), will it break the Context API that is used to pass data around? especially from the Service Layer to the Interceptor? Not sure, if the Context API uses ThreadLocal internally.